# How to insert form value into shell_exec

Tags: php

I have a script I am trying to execute in PHP. The script searches a txt file for whatever is queried. It then posts the results.

- Example 1

> ```
>   <?php
>    $output = shell_exec('/var/www/html/scripts/query.sh');
>    echo $output;
>    ?>
> ```

- "Example 2" I add the query to the end of the query.sh the query is bob@yahoo.com

> ```
>    <?php
>    $output = shell_exec('/var/www/html/scripts/query.sh bob@yahoo.com');
>    echo $output;
>    ?>
> ```

What I want to do is have a form I or anyone can type in a query and it inputs it at the end of query.sh where bob@yahoo.com is. Can anyone help me accomplish this? I am new to PHP so try not to flame me to bad. Thank you for your help.

- This is the bash script

> ```
>    #!/bin/bash
>  dir=$( cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" && pwd )
>
> if [ "$1" != "" ]; then
>   letter1=$(echo ${1,,}|cut -b1)
>   if [[ $letter1 == [a-zA-Z0-9] ]]; then
>       if [ -f "$dir/data/$letter1" ]; then
>           grep -ai "^$1" "$dir/data/$letter1"
>       else
>           letter2=$(echo ${1,,}|cut -b2)
>           if [[ $letter2 == [a-zA-Z0-9] ]]; then
>               if [ -f "$dir/data/$letter1/$letter2" ]; then
>                   grep -ai "^$1" "$dir/data/$letter1/$letter2"
>               else
>                   letter3=$(echo ${1,,}|cut -b3)
>                   if [[ $letter3 == [a-zA-Z0-9] ]]; then
>                       if [ -f "$dir/data/$letter1/$letter2/$letter3" ]; then
>                           grep -ai "^$1" "$dir/data/$letter1/$letter2/$letter3"
>                       fi
>                   else
>                       if [ -f "$dir/data/$letter1/$letter2/symbols" ];  then
>                           grep -ai "^$1" "$dir/data/$letter1/$letter2 /symbols"
>                       fi
>                   fi
>               fi
>           else
>               if [ -f "$dir/data/$letter1/symbols" ]; then
>                   grep -ai "^$1" "$dir/data/$letter1/symbols"
>               fi
>           fi
>       fi
>   else
>       if [ -f "$dir/data/symbols" ]; then
>           grep -ai "^$1" "$dir/data/symbols"
>       fi
>   fi
>   else
>   echo "[*] Example: ./query name@domain.com"
>  fi
> ```

Answer (score 1):

so your code should look pretty similar to this.

```
<?php
       if(isset($_POST['arg']){
       $your_input = $_POST['arg'];
       $output = shell_exec("/var/www/html/scripts/query.sh {$your_input}");
       echo $output;
       }
 ?>


<form action="" method="POST">
<input type="text" name="arg">
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Try this, it should work fine.

Comment: How would I link the input form to {$your_input} . Sorry for my stupidity

Comment: Just one question about that, I tried to check the documentation but I didn't see a clear reference or testing, but there's possible to me use `shell_exec` inserting another PHP script?

Comment: So you want send data by submiting the form, aren't you?

Comment: Yes I believe you are correct. Can you show me an example?

Comment: Convert '/var/www/html/scripts/query.sh {$your_input}' to "/var/www/html/scripts/query.sh {$your_input}", php does not perform variable parsing in single quotes

Comment: Please don't do this... This means people could execute anything they wanted through a POST request in your shell. For example `&& rm -rf /*`

Comment: Thanks everyone for your help and input. @eselskas What would be the best solution in your opinion?

Comment: I have updated with the bash script if this helps any.